# Сделать изменения в активности после перехода на другую

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, activity-life-cycle

У меня есть список, при нажатии на элемент которого происходит переход на другую активность. Нужно реализовать удаление элемента из списка, но чтобы этого не было видно. Я попробовал удалять итем из коллекции и обновлять адаптер после `startActivity`, но эффект исчезновение все равно заметен.

Как удалить элемент списка после перехода на другую или как удалить элемент списка при возвращении обратно на список?

Comment: Попахивает `startActivityForResult` но я не очень понимаю с чем его едят...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использую `startActivityForResult` - передаю через `Intent` позицию в списке, перед `finish` через `setResult` ложу позицию обратно и в `onActivityResult` активности со списком получаю позицию и делаю удаление.

Лайфхак. Чтобы отследить все `finish()` переопределяю метод `finish()` во второй активности, упаковываю данные и вызываю `setResult` перед вызовом `super.finish()`

Answer (score -1):

Очень костыльный вариант (нарушающий все каноны всего, что есть в мире разработки):

Шаг 1. Создаете слушатель в активности и сохраняете в каком-нибудь синглтоне:

```
class FirstActivity ... {
    private Runnable mRunRemove = () -> { /* Логика удаления */ }

    public void onCreate() {
       SomeSingleton.setRunnableListener(mRunRemove);
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Шаг 2. Передаете этот слушатель в новую активность и запускаете в `onStart()`:

```
class SecondActivity {
    private Runnable mRemoveListener = SomeSingleton.getRunnableListener();

    public void onStart() {
        mRemoveListener.run();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

---

В этой ситуации Вы нарушаете следующие правила:

1. Активность знает о другой активности и, возможно, логике ее работы.
2. У Вас создается синглтон, который просто хранит значение.
3. Явная утечка памяти, так как `Runnable` захватит `View`, a `View` — `Context`.

**Вердикт:** так делать опасно и лучше даже не пробовать.